# Wordpress Functions.php file doesn't enqueue anything

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why, but my functions.php file doesn't load any script/style. This is my functions.php file:

```
<?php

function promotie_load_styles() {
    /* If this is the admin area of WordPress, don't do anything */
    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script('latest-jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js');

    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    wp_register_script('html5shiv', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv');
    wp_register_script('respond','https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('respond');

    // bootstrap stuff
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-js',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');

    wp_register_style('bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'promotie_load_styles');
```

What is the problem here? I am simply adding action to wp_enqueue_scripts and enqueue scripts/styles, but when I inspect the page, and go to Resources, there is nothing there, no style, no script.

EDIT1: Another strange thing is that my theme used to work without functions.php file, I was loading the scripts in the header, before reading more about enqueuing. Now, I created the functions.php and nothing gets imported properly. I added some random text there and no error is returned, and if I type something outside the function, it gets echoed in the html page.

My guess is that there is an error somewhere, but I don't know how to debug it, I have the WP_DEBUG set to true in wp-config, I don't really know what to do.

Comment: this script is working here. you might be login in admin

Comment: I removed that line to have no doubt, still no success, nothing gets loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most probably missing `wp_head()` inside the `<head></head>` tag

Comment: this was the problem, thank you very much! Can you please give me some references on how to debug ? I don't really know to debug and finding some issues is very hard without knowing where to look for.

Comment: The codex have a very useful article [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). The problem with the problem you had, it will fail silently, so even if you debug, you will not get any errors